# Zeitgeist stats

Tags: feature-request, tags, statistics

There is the stats feature for single tags. But have you ever thought of giving away data about the **overall development** of tags? Like, how many questions tagged "foo" were asked in a certain interval, and a timeline of the most important or most differing (in time) tags?

I think it could be quite interesting. Although the evidence of how en vogue something is is not given by such a graph, it would nevertheless give an impartial position on some personal thoughts (like, *'Oh dear, I could swear there were no FORTRAN questions in the last two months... And those I like best.'*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Word:

[StatOverflow](http://www.statoverflow.com/sandbox/)

Additional Word:

[SPWho2](http://spwho2.com/)

<sub>Long Answer: Feel free to access any of the above listed data dumps to generate the data required for such an analysis</sub>

Comment: Cool. That quite answered my question (except for graphical evaluation). Thanks!